# casting a REAL as INT and comparing

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am casting a `real` to an `int` and a `float` to an `int` and comparing the two like this:

```
  where
  cast(a.[SUM(PAID_AMT)] as int)!=cast(b.PAID_AMT as int)
```

but i am still getting results where the two are equal. for example:

```
+-----------+-----------+------------+------------+----------+
|   accn    |  load_dt  |   pmtdt    | sumpaidamt | Bpaidamt |
+-----------+-----------+------------+------------+----------+
| A133312   | 6/7/2011  | 11/28/2011 | 98.39      | 98.39    |
| A445070   | 6/2/2011  | 9/22/2011  | 204.93     | 204.93   |
| A465606   | 5/19/2011 | 10/19/2011 | 560.79     | 560.79   |
| A508742   | 7/12/2011 | 10/19/2011 | 279.65     | 279.65   |
| A567730   | 5/27/2011 | 10/24/2011 | 212.76     | 212.76   |
| A617277   | 7/12/2011 | 10/12/2011 | 322.02     | 322.02   |
| A626384   | 6/16/2011 | 10/21/2011 | 415.84     | 415.84   |
| AA0000044 | 5/12/2011 | 5/23/2011  | 197.38     | 197.38   |
+-----------+-----------+------------+------------+----------+
```

here is the full query:

```
select 
  a.accn,
  a.load_dt,
  a.pmtdt,
  a.[SUM(PAID_AMT)] sumpaidamt,
  sum(b.paid_amt) Bpaidamt
  from
  [MILLENNIUM_DW_DEV].[dbo].[Millennium_Payment_Data_May2011_July2012] a
  join
  F_PAYOR_PAYMENTS_DAILY b
  on
  a.accn=b.ACCESSION_ID
  and
  a.final_rpt_dt=b.FINAL_REPORT_DATE
  and
  a.load_dt=b.LOAD_DATE
  and
  a.pmtdt=b.PAYMENT_DATE
  where
  cast(a.[SUM(PAID_AMT)] as int)!=cast(b.PAID_AMT as int) 

  group by 
    a.accn,

  a.load_dt,
  a.pmtdt,
  a.[SUM(PAID_AMT)]
```

what am i doing wrong? how do i return only records that are NOT equal?

Comment: I take it you've never heard of floating-point issues?  Monetary values should **NEVER** be represented in floating-point types (for one thing, you can't represent `.1` exactly).  The rest is probably just rounding at some point, but would prefer sample data to check.

Comment: @X-Zero thank you. should i be casting as something different?

Comment: You should be **storing** the data as either an integer-based type (in cents, or what have you), or in an fixed-precision decimal type; I believe that `DECIMAL` and `NUMERIC` are the standard types, although some RDBMSs have a custom `MONEY` (or similar) type.  You shouldn't need to cast anything for the comparison, it should compare exactly just fine.  Please note that, while most amounts will _probably_ give results within a cent of the 'expected' total, past a certain point the 'minimum' difference is much larger (like not being able to represent differences of 1 or less, and it gets worse)

Comment: @X-Zero so just to reiterate, money should never be stored as FLOAT right?

Comment: Money (or anything that needs to be stored as an _exact_ value, like manufacturing sizes) should **NEVER** (ever ever ever) be stored as a floating-point (`FLOAT`, `REAL`, `DOUBLE`, whatever) value.  There's a number of questions on here about problems with floating-point arithmetic, and using `DECIMAL` for storing money.  If for no other reason than you can't accurately store/add a cent.

Answer (score 3):

I don't see why there is an issue.

The query is returning the *sum* of the payments in b (sum(b.paid_amt) Bpaidamt).  The where clause is comparing individual payments.  This just means that there is more than one payment.

Perhaps your intention is to have a HAVING clause instead:

```
having cast(a.[SUM(PAID_AMT)] as int)!=cast(sum(b.PAID_AMT) as int)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do a round and a cast statement.

`cast(round(sumpaidamt,2) as money) <> cast(round(Bpaidamt,2) as money)`

Sql Fiddle showing how it would work http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4eb79/1